# Error while Implementing setDisallowed setAllowed for Sumo and Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to implement a TraCi command for mysumo scenario (traci.lane.setDisallowed) while using veins. I created a new command in the TraciCommandInterface.cpp like:

```
void TraCICommandInterface::Lane::setDisallowed(std::list<std::string> disallowedClasses)
{
    TraCIBuffer buf = connection->query(CMD_SET_LANE_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << LANE_DISALLOWED << laneId << TYPE_STRINGLIST << disallowedClasses);
    ASSERT(buf.eof());
}
```

and called like:

```
std::list<std::string> disallowedClasses = {"all"};
if (simTime()==20) {
    TraCICommandInterface* cInt = getCommandInterface();
    cInt->lane("ed_1_0").setDisallowed(disallowedClasses);
}
```

The problem is that i get the error:
Answered with error to command 0xc3: Wrong position in requestMessage after dispatching command 195. Expected command length was 38 but 18 Bytes were read.

Is there something wrong with the way i implemented the command? Any suggestions why this problems occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Veins 5.0, `TraCIBuffer` only has a few overloads for C++ data types, notably for `std::string`, `simtime_t`, and `TraCICoord` (see [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.h#L157)). All other types are sent as stored in memory (by casting to `char*`) (see [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.h#L71)) - certainly not a good idea for `std::list`.

For copy/paste-able code for how to serialize a `std::list<std::string>` to a binary blob representing the `TYPE_STRINGLIST` SUMO/TraCI expects, see the code of `TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::changeVehicleRoute(const std::list<std::string>& edges)`, available [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc#L965).